# phantomjs command does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

```
phantom.casperPath = './node_modules/casperjs';
phantom.injectJs('./node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');

var fs = require('fs')

var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,//The script is much faster when this field is set to 
false
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
}
});
//open Facebook
casper.start().thenOpen("https://dcid.dcinside.com/join/login.php?",
  function() {
    console.log("dcinside website opened");
  });

//login
casper.then(function() {
  console.log("Log in with the appropriate id and pw.");
  this.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("email").value = "chermy018";
    document.getElementById("pass").value = "kl424321";
    document.getElementById("loginbutton").children[0].click();
  });
});
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "http://gallog.dcinside.com/inc/_mylog.php?gid=chermy018&oneview=Y&cid=59&page=1";

request(url, function(err, res, html) {
  if (!err) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  }
  console.log(html);
})

casper.run();
```

for the purpose of parsing my diary over 800 pages, i looked parsing method in which can handle parsing the login needed pages. and revised original to seems look like appropriate one to parsing my diary on the website. by reference what i took, it should run by command "phantomjs filename". but cmd can't handle phantomjs command. l already installed 'phantomjs' and 'casperjs'. can you correct code if it has problems for the purpose and what can solve symptoms.

Comment: Are you using CasperJS or node.js? Why is there `request` module in the script?

Comment: I'm using node.js , i borrowed 'request' and 'cheerio' in previous testing js file which i used to test to know How parse pages. i typed that because i think that load pages.

Comment: @joung-joonlee is your casperjs+phantomjs environment setup in proper working condition?

Comment: it look like cmd doesn't result version of casperjs+phantomjs

Comment: `I'm using node.js` In that case you shouldn't write script that can only be run by CasperJS! CasperJS is not a node.js module, it's a separate binary. May I suggest that you work through a tutorial on scraping with node.js? Logging in would then be just another POST request before everything else.